# Using dropzone.js within a knockout binding

Tags: knockout.js, dropzone.js

I am trying to get dropzone to work as a knockout binding.  I would really like to be able to...

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dropzone = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
        $(element).dropzone({ url: 'some/tightly/bound/uri});
    }
}
```

.. but I cannot.  The uri is dynamic based on data entered in the viewmodel, so this is what I have come up with so far:

```
var dropzoneObject; // probably should be this.dropzoneObject

ko.bindingHandlers.dropzone = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
        var url = allBindingsAccessor().urlPath || "unknown";
        dropzoneObject = new Dropzone("div#" + element.id, {
            url: url, 
            init: ...,
            etc
        });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
        var url = allBindingsAccessor().urlPath || "unknown";
        dropzoneObject.options = {
            url: url
        };
    }
}
```

but when I test this, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefinedDropzone.defaultOptions.addedfile 
@ dropzone.js:252Emitter.emit @ dropzone.js:58Dropzone.addFile 
@ dropzone.js:956(anonymous function) @ dropzone.js:563
```

Why is it `undefinedDropzone`? What have I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer, my update method was over writing all the options (including the default ones) rather than updating it so:

```
....
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    var url = allBindingsAccessor().urlPath || "unknown";
    dropzoneObject.options = {
        url: url
    };
}
....
```

Should read:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, bindingContext) {
    var url = allBindingsAccessor().urlPath || "unknown";
    dropzoneObject.options.url = url;
}
```

Hope this helps someone!